# Htmlentities issue with form display

Tags: php

I am pulling data from a table in my database and inserting it into a form - therefore I can edit it and save it back to the table.

My current problem is my data in the table has HTML characters like

```
<br /><br />
```

which as we all know are line breaks - I don't want them to display like html characters though... In the textarea where I have outputted them to I would like them to just display as line breaks within the text area...

I have tried using htmlentities and htmlspecialchars with no luck.

Comment: And `<b>` makes text in html bold. Do you want it to be bold in textarea as well?

Comment: Well I would like it to cooperate with all HTML characters, it is up to what exactly has been placed in the textarea. I haven't really bothered with bold but that is not to say other people will not and so it would be useful if the textarea would just style to how the HTML is set up by taking the appropriate line breaks etc.. - in saying that I could probably just install a WYSIWYG editor but most of them are ugly and I'd like to keep things simple.

Comment: @Andrew if my solution helps please tick the correct solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert the linebreaks then use phps nl2br() function.

The approach to have the textarea render html markup: this won't work. It simply is not supported. A textarea tag supports text, not markup. That is something different. You will either have to stick with plain text or use one of the js based wysiwyg editors.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know how to fetch those data from mysql table so I will skip that, just add this:-

```
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" >
<?
echo "$name\n\n";
echo "$age";
?>
</textarea>
```